# Steps to create a widget on Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I have the following code on a given view:

```
<?php
    $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'home-newsletter-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
        'enableClientValidation' => true,
            ));

    echo $form->textField($newsletterSubscribeForm, 'email');
    echo $form->error($newsletterSubscribeForm, 'email');
    echo CHtml::link("subscribe", "#", array('class'=>'btSubscribe'));
    $this->endWidget(); 
?>
```

It happens that I will need this on MORE then one view, so I find a widget a better option.
I wish however to place this on a separate file (on app/widgets/ folder), and called on each view.

Can anyone please be kind enough to tell me what steps should we follow in order to achieve that?

Comment: perhaps it's not easy done, if not, I do forget. Just let me know.

Comment: Did you read this? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.view#widget

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Widget is the best solution here, it will keep your code DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself - focus on re-usability) as well.

```
<?php

// protected/components/SubscriberFormWidget.php

class SubscriberFormWidget extends CWidget
{
    /**
     * @var CFormModel
     */
    public $form;

    public function run()
    {
        if (! $this->form instanceof CFormModel) {
            throw new RuntimeException('No valid form available.');
        }
        $this->render('subscriberFormWidget', array('form'=>$this->form));
    }
}
```

And the view:

```
<?php
// protected/components/views/subscriberFormWidget.php

$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'home-newsletter-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
));

echo $form->textField($newsletterSubscribeForm, 'email');
echo $form->error($newsletterSubscribeForm, 'email');
echo CHtml::link("subscribe", "#", array('class'=>'btSubscribe'));
$this->endWidget();
```

sample usage inside any view

```
<?php $this->widget('SubscriberFormWidget', array(
        'form' => $newsletterSubscribeForm
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 18):

Creating a widget is very simple in Yii. It couldn't be better explained than in the following short official documentation section, [Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.view#widget).

I little emphasis as lots of people found this answer useful. The following words are at my own taste, how I prefer designing my Yii application building blocks: when building your widget class always bear in mind that a widget is a kind of a view in Yii (v1.x). Its not supposed to process stuff, to perform important business logic decisions. Rather, as a view it merely supposed *to render* stuff. The decision making code in it should be focused in finding out what to render. I used to design in the past widgets that included some AJAX processing. Today I think this is bad design. A widget should render stuff. Need an accompanying processing unit? I would pack it all in a [module](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module), with controllers, possibly model classes, and the widget as an extension in that module. Cest tout :-)

Answer (score 4):

You are better of using [partials views](http://yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController/#renderPartial-detail).

Like this:

```
<?php $this->renderPartial('//partials/_myview',
        compact('model', 'dataProvider')
); ?>
```

that way you can reuse the code in other views.

Comment: Widgets are not the solution for everything either. in this case, the best solution for his problem are partials, he doesnt need a Widgetyou say they are not. but you give no reasons...

Comment: I mean, that replace widgets with partials - is not the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Steps to create widget

```
<?php
//protected/components
    class Categorywidget extends CWidget
    {

        public function init(){

        }

        public function run(){
            $model=Category::model()->findAll(array("condition"=>"isactive=1"));
            $listdata=CHtml::listData($model,"category_id","name");
            $this->render("category/category",array('listdata'=>$listdata));
        }

    }




 <?php
//protected/components/views
    $count=count($listdata);
    $div2=ceil($count/2)+1;
    $i=0;
    ?>
                <div class="categories">
                    <h5>Categories</h5>
                    <ul>
    <?php           foreach($listdata as $key=>$value) {
                        $i++;
                        if($div2==$i){ ?>
                        </ul><ul>    
    <?php               } ?>                
                        <li><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("medialist/".$this->REQUEST,array("category"=>$key)); ?>" class="colr"><?php echo $value; ?></a></li>
    <?php           } ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **2 minutes** I've understand how widgets work in this very **short tutorial**:
**[How to create Breadcrumb widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/23/)**

Answer (score -1):

It's easy to create a widget in Yii, Just follow the link. [Create Yii Widget](http://www.waytoblogger.com/2012/09/29/create-yii-widget-using-cportlet/)

Comment: Nothing about Yii or widgets at the link.