# Login form in header on every page in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii-components, yii2

How can I display a login form in header navigation on every page using Yii2?

I tried to use:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin(..);
$form->field(..);
ActiveForm:end();
```

But I'll have to add LoginForm model for each page in site controller.

Is there a better way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: put your code in mail.php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- You have to put your code in widget

2- in your widget view you need to define absolute action path ,
like this :

```
            <?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                'id' => 'contact-form',
                'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl('//index.php/site/contact'),
                'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                'enableClientValidation' => false,
                'clientOptions' => array(
                    'validateOnSubmit' => true,
                ),
                'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form'),
            ));
            ?>
```

In Yii2 :

```
// In Yii 2
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'method' => 'get',
        'action' => Url::to(['//index.php/site/contact']),
]);

// In Yii 1.x
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', [
        'method' => 'get',
        'action' => $this->createUrl('//index.php/site/contact'),
]);
```

Related link:
[Steps to create a widget on Yii?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447959/steps-to-create-a-widget-on-yii)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Looks like your method only for yii 1.*, do you know how to make the same in yii 2? Thx.

Comment: I'll have to add model in each controller anyway.
For example, that's how the login controller do:
`$model = new LoginForm();
...
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
...`
But i want to use this form on each page of my site, so it's not a good way actually. But thanks for your time anyway! :)